# Joomla - get one year and one month time()

Tags: joomla

I can get the current date&time by using

```
$today = JHTML::_('date', time(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
echo $today;
```

How to I get 1year later and 1month later base on $today??

eg.now:2011-12-10 13:00:01
How to get 2012-12-10 13:00:01 AND 2012-01-10 13:00:01

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best way to do it, but this should work:

```
$time = mktime( date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m")+1, date("d"), date("Y") + 1);
JHTML::_( 'date', $time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

Alternatively, if you are using PHP 5.3, you can use the [DateTime object](http://es.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).

I hope it helped!